# Joi extension for escaping html tags

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I want to create extension for sanitizing string inputs and stripping off the html tags.

For this, I am using [sanitize-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html) npm package.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
const sanitizeHtml = require('sanitize-html');

module.exports = function htmlStrip(joi) {
  return {
    type: 'htmlStrip',
    base: joi.string(),
    messages: {
      htmlStrip: 'Should not contain any html tags.',
    },
    validate(value, helpers) {
      const clean = sanitizeHtml(value, {
        allowedTags: [],
        allowedAttributes: {},
      });
      if (clean) {
        return clean;
      }
      return { value, errors: helpers.error('htmlStrip') };
    },
  };
};
```

But I am getting below error.

> TypeError: Joi.string(...).trim(...).htmlStrip is not a function

I also have tried passing rules object as below, but still getting the same error.

```
const sanitizeHtml = require('sanitize-html');

module.exports = function htmlStrip(joi) {
  return {
    type: 'htmlStrip',
    base: joi.string(),
    messages: {
      htmlStrip: 'Should not contain any html tags.',
    },
    rules: {
      htmlStrip: {
        validate(params, value, state, options) {
          const clean = sanitizeHtml(value, {
            allowedTags: [],
            allowedAttributes: {},
          });
          if (clean) {
            return clean;
          }
          return this.createError('string.htmlStrip', { value }, state, options);
        },
      },
    },
  };
};
```

I was following the doc mentioned [here](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.2.1#extensions).

This is how I am using the extended validator.

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi').extend(require('@hapi/joi-date')).extend(require('../utils/sanitize-html-joi'));

const validateAddressCreateData = (data) => {
  const schema = Joi.object({
    address: Joi.string().trim().htmlStrip().required(),
    label: Joi.string()
      .required(),
  });
  return schema.validate(data);
};
```

Comment: Please include the full error stack. It will make it easier to see where the error comes from.

Comment: @Molda Added the code from where the error is popping up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you assumed that type of `Joi.string().trim()` is going to be the same as `Joi`, considering you extend `Joi` object, yet expect `htmlStrip` to be available on `Joi.string().trim()` result.

Simple console.log for both types shows that they are different types.

`console.log(Object.keys(Joi))`:

```
[ '_types',
  'alternatives',
  'any',
  'array',
  'boolean',
  ...
  'htmlStrip' ]
```

`console.log(Object.keys(Joi.string().trim());`:

```
[ 'type',
  '$_root',
  '$_temp',
  '_ids',
  '_preferences',
  '_valids',
  '_invalids',
  '_rules',
  '_singleRules',
  '_refs',
  '_flags',
  '_cache',
  '$_terms',
  '$_super' ]
```

`trim`'s result `$_super` does not seem to contain any keys, so they're not really related.

I believe if you want to pre-process your input and *then* use your `htmlStrip`, you'd have to do something like this:

```
const sanitizeHtml = require('sanitize-html');

module.exports = function htmlStrip(joi) {
  return {
    type: 'htmlStrip',
    base: joi.string(),
    messages: {
      htmlStrip: 'Should not contain any html tags.',
    },
    validate(value, helpers) {
      const clean = sanitizeHtml(value, {
        allowedTags: [],
        allowedAttributes: {},
      });
      if (clean == value) {
        return { clean, errors: [] };
      }
      return { value, errors: helpers.error('htmlStrip') };
    },
  };
};
```

Here's how I'm using it:

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi').extend(require('@hapi/joi-date')).extend(require('./san'));

const validateAddressCreateData = (data) => {
  const schema = Joi.object({
    address: Joi.htmlStrip(Joi.string().trim()).required(),
    label: Joi.string().required(),
  });
  return schema.validate(data);
};

console.log(validateAddressCreateData({ address: "<body>test</body>", label: "abc"}));
```

But I'm not sure if the output is as you expect it to be:

```
{ value: { address: '<body>test</body>', label: 'abc' },
  error:
   { ValidationError: Should not contain any html tags.
     _original: { address: '<body>test</body>', label: 'abc' },
     details: [ [Object] ] } }
```

So, it seems to validate the input according to the validation message defined. Or do you actually want to **modify** the address html being passed?

**Edit** got your point now, modified `htmlStrip` accordingly. Please see the comparison `if(value == clean)`. In case the sanitizer didn't have to trim anything, it means that input string does not contain any html tags. Return error in other case.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. I didn't get any validation error if I send html tags in the string. Also, you are right, I want to attach other validation on that before passing it to stripHTML.

Comment: Edited the output a bit. Do you actually want to modify the string being passed to validator? But would that be semantically correct? I believe that validator shouldn't mutate the object being validated...just check if it's correct.

Comment: There is one problem here, this function `sanitizeHtml` is sanitizing the input rather than informing if it contains some html tags which can be used for XSS attacks. I don't want to modify the input rather I want to inform the user the data is invalid.

Comment: Well I believe the error `ValidationError: Should not contain any html tags.` pretty much says it all, right? Apparently, it does contain html tags.

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense `if (clean) { return { clean, errors: helpers.error('htmlStrip') }; }
return { value, errors: helpers.error('htmlStrip') };`
In all cases it will return error no mattere if it contains html tags or not.

Comment: Got your point now, simply do a comparison `if(clean == value)` - in such case, sanitizer didn't have to trim anything. Edited answer accordingly.

Comment: There i an issue with this solution.
If our string contains any characters like '&' or '>' it will throw error .
Its because the sanitize-html npm module we use will escape these characters , for example < is converted to &lt; , and because of that the clean == value will be false , even if it doesnot have proper html content but have characters like '>'

Answer (score 0):

Export Joi with Custom validation will solve this ( *custom_joi.js* )

```
const sanitizeHtml = require('sanitize-html');
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi')

module.exports = Joi.extend((joi) => ({
 type: "string",
 base: joi.string(),
 messages: {
    "string.htmlStrip": "{{#label}} not contain any html tags"
 },
 rules: {
 htmlStrip: {
  validate(value, helpers) {
    const clean = sanitizeHtml(value, {
      allowedTags: [],
      allowedAttributes: {},
    });
    if (clean == value) {
      return clean;
    }
    return helpers.error("string.htmlStrip")
  }
} } } ) )
```

And import our custom file in controller

```
const Joi = require('../../_helpers/custom_joi');
```

then create validation schema

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
notes: Joi.string().htmlStrip().allow('', null),
specialInstructions: Joi.string().htmlStrip()
});
const { error, value } = schema.validate(req.body);
```